# I need a macro for excel that searches for anything in column F that has a comma in it

Tags: excel, vba

I then need this macro to split the results into 2 separate cells. Basically:

"Individual Investors, Invus Group"

Needs to be found and converted into 2 separate cells down the column into:

Individual Investors
Invus Group

Something easier to read would be : A,B,C needs to be changed into
A
B
C

Answer (score -2):

Nvm, figured it out!

Text to Columns

- select cell F7
- CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN
- Data tab > Text to Columns
- - Delimited > Next
- - check only COMMA > Next
- - set Destination to S7 (so we dont overwrite her data)
- - finish